# NDB Query builder doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, dev-appserver

I have the following query in my application

`query = cls.query().filter(cls.taskgroup_id == taskgroup_id, cls.availability == True, cls.task_id > min_task_id).order(cls.task_id)
query.fetch(1)`

Above works fine as expected. (Fetches only those entities, which match taskgroup_id, and is available, and task_id > min_task_id)

However, when I break query into multiple statements.

```
query = cls.query()
query.filter(cls.taskgroup_id == taskgroup_id)
query.filter(cls.availability == True)
query.filter(cls.task_id > min_task_id)
```

It doesn't work as expected.

When I run [2], query formation broken down into multiple statements, it returns me a entity whose availability is False, and task_id is equal to min_task_id.

[2] doesn't work as expected (or as I expect). I think there is a user error here. Wondering what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Filtering by Property Values](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> query = Account.query(Account.userid >= 40, Account.userid < 50)
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Instead of specifying an entire query filter in a single expression,
>   you may find it more convenient to build it up in steps: for example:
>
> [appengine/standard/ndb/queries/snippets.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/ndb/queries/snippets.py)
>
> ```
> query1 = Account.query()  # Retrieve all Account entitites
> query2 = query1.filter(Account.userid >= 40)  # Filter on userid >= 40
> query3 = query2.filter(Account.userid < 50)  # Filter on userid < 50 too
> ```
>
> `query3` is equivalent to the `query` variable from the previous
>   example. **Note that query objects are immutable**, so the construction of
>   `query2` does not affect `query1` and the construction of `query3`
>   does not affect `query1` or `query2`.

In other words for your example none of the `query.filter()` statements actually modifies `query`.

Just assign the results of the statements to local variables and use those instead, just as in the quoted example.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know query objects were immutable. Wonder what the rationale behind that is. Assigning results to temporary variables (though solves the problem), makes it ugly in my opinion ( i might be wrong, and there is a good reason to do that, i guess).

Comment: For one it gives the ability to contruct one or more related queries with one or more filters added conditionally (for example filters configurable and selectable by the user via GUI). If the query wouldn't be immutable queries would have to built from scratch all over the place in a potentially complex conditional logic - non-DRY and more error prone IMHO.

Comment: Interesting. I thought, advising to create temp variables, because of immutability is just as error prone. It is very common to see bugs where query1 will be used instead of query2 (query3 = query1.filter(*) instead of query2.filter(*). And since it is a logical bug, debugging will take more time than expected. Would be better if they provide a mutable query object, just like Java provides StringBuilder(mutable), along with String(immutable)

Comment: If you don't plan on reusing any of the intermediate queries, then just use the same variable name each time.