# Datastore query sort order by newest date

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've read the documentation on how to do this but it is not working. I am trying to get my query to sort by date newest first, but this is not working:

```
wrQuery = WorkRequest.query()
wrQuery.order('-date')
wrResult = wrQuery.fetch()
```

I have also tried `('-WorkRequest.date')` but both results in similar errors:

> TypeError: order() expects a Property or query Order; received '-date'

Answer (score 1):

The query objects are immutable, your 3rd statement references the object from your 1st statement, not the ordered one created in the 2nd statement. See also [NDB Query builder doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689781/ndb-query-builder-doesnt-work-as-expected/40689859#40689859).

This should work instead:

```
 wrQuery = WorkRequest.query()
 wrOrderedQuery = wrQuery.order('-WorkRequest.date')
 wrResult = wrOrderedQuery.fetch()
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are using NDB rather than DataStore, in which case the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#order) show you unequivocally how to do it. This should work:

```
wrQuery = wrQuery.order(-WorkRequest.date)
```